# How to solve duplication issue in List of items?

Tags: flutter

When I retrieve some items there are some duplicates. I want to remove them but I can't. I have tried simple `toSet().toList()` solution but it does not work. Anything that works?

Article Model consists of:

```
final String id;
final String author;
final String caption;
```

The function code:

```
SearchItem(User user,int page,String searchfield,List<String> tags,bool tagsearch,int pl,int ph,bool searchbasedonlocation,bool priceactivated) async {

  List<Article> articlesfinal = [];
  if(tagsearch){searchfield = newtags(tags);}
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("$url"), headers: <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json');
  final parsed = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  List<Article> users = parsed["results"] != null ? new List<Article>.from( parsed["results"].map((x) => Article.fromJSON(x))) : List<Article>();


  final response2 = await http.get(Uri.parse("$url") ,headers: <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json');
  final parsed2 = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response2.bodyBytes));
  List<Article> users2 = parsed2["results"] != null ? new List<Article>.from( parsed2["results"].map((x) => Article.fromJSON(x))) : List<Article>();
  users = users.toSet().toList();
  users2 = users2.toSet().toList();
  articlesfinal.addAll(users);
  articlesfinal.addAll(users2);
  
  
  return articlesfinal.toSet().toList();
}
```

Comment: If a entry is inside ```users``` and ```users2``` then it can show up as duplicate in ```articlesfinal```. Can you try removing the duplicates from the ```articlesfinal``` ?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69170301/15117201

Comment: @glory9211 uh.. i already did?? `return articlesfinal.toSet().toList();`

Comment: @JahnE. can you please provide explanations to the code rather than pointing out to a complete different structure i am not able to understand?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using hash function inside Article model

```
  @override
  operator ==(o) => o.id == id && o.caption== caption;

  @override
  int get hashCode => hashValues(id,caption);
```

And after that using `articlesfinal.toSet().toList()` solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the equality operator in your model, otherwise it won't be able to know whether or not two objects of your model are equal. This package makes it easier for cases like this: [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)

After adding the package extend `Equatable`:

```
class Article extends Equatable
```

And then add properties you want to check for equality:

```
@override
List<Object?> get props => [id, author, caption];
```

Comment: I have added the codes you mentioned.Do i have to change SearchItem() function or thats all?

Comment: I have inserted the codes and it still does not work

Comment: @umarbeyoglu Could you update your question and include the full code to your model updated model as well? Also put this right before the return statement `print(articlesfinal.toSet().toList());` and include its output as well.

Comment: I have solved with help of a friend in Discord.I will share the codes now.